# Customizing placement of report parameters

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I creating a report in Report Builder 3.0.

I'm having problems adjusting the layout of the selection parameters - see image:

[image: Report parameters]

I would like the parameters to be on the same line, but I cant seem to figure out how this is done.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would like to see more ability to customise the parameter bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. This service automatically sets them up two across then down.

[Microsoft Report Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220464.aspx)